# Require complete subdirectories, with grunt-neuter

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following directory structure for my ember application:

```
neuter/
├── adapters
├── controllers
├── models
├── routes
└── views
```

In all those directories I have lots of files. Currently, my `neuterapp.js` has lots of statements like:

```
require('app/neuter/models/node');
require('app/neuter/controllers/nodes');
```

I would like to avoid having to explicitly list all files which are needed. I have tried with:

```
require('app/neuter/controllers/*');
```

And with:

```
require('app/neuter/controllers');
```

But this is not working. Is there any way to require everything in a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
require('app/neuter/models/**/*')
```

This addition was added with [this merged PR](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember/pull/35).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great! Moving to `grunt-neuter-0.5.0` solved my problems. Now I can use `require('app/neuter/controllers/*');` (I was using `0.4.0`)